# NSInternalInconsistencyException while running VOIP enabled apps on iOS13

Tags: voip, ios13, xcode11

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'PushKit apps that use VoIP push must link either CallKit or IncomingCallNotifications frameworks.'

This error is displayed on xcode 11 Beta that uses iOS 13. 
No issue on xcode10.

PushKit apps that use VoIP push must link either CallKit or IncomingCallNotifications frameworks. #voip

Comment: Solution to this issue is mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58117847/2481161

Answer (score 7):

> Embedding **CallKit.framework** in General Settings of the Project resolves this issue.
>
> On iOS 13, Apple now mandates that all VoIP push notifications be reported to the CallKit framework as a new call

**Important changes mentioned here:**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry?language=objc

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117939

Comment: It solved the crash issue. But, I guess this is not the actual solution.

Comment: This is for existing apps who already report to CallKit but did not embed CallKit previously. But Starting from iOS13 we need to Embed it.

Comment: Naga Mallesh Maddali, how did you solve that issue?